# Is there a way to return a function and take a closure without lifetimes?

Tags: rust

I have this:

```
fn with_name<P>(name: &'static str) -> impl Fn(P) -> String
where
    P: Fn(&str) -> Markup,
{
    move |t| render(t(name))
}
```

I'm looking for my API to be used like:

```
with_name("hi")(|title: &str| html! { ... })
```

This works, but wasm_bindgen can't do lifetime/type parameters. Is this over-engineered? Is there a better way?

Comment: *Is there a way to return a function and take a closure without lifetimes* — yes, don't use any references.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. We don't know what your build process involving `wasm_bindgen` is. Ideally, produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org). There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.